# Two URLs that you can use to hit the homepage

Tags: redirect, seo, sitecore

Having a sitecore website. Situation is for every country, there are two URLs that you can use to hit the homepage.

> www.abc.com/en/home

and

> www.abc.com/en

We only want one - this is bad for both SEO and analytics. 
I want to retire www.abc.com/en/home and want www.abc.com/en to only work.

I already worked with embedded URL = always in web.config but didn't worked for me.

Comment: This is due to how your sitedefinitions are set up rather then language embedding. Can you add your sitedefinition?

Comment: Here it is : 

 <site name="website" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false"/>

Comment: Your site definition is correct. I just tested it on one of my projects and found the same behavior. I'll write an answer with my recommended action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use LanguageEmbedding.Always in the LinkManager.
Links generated with the Sitecore LinkManager have always a language code.
But the other urls will also work.

You can use a Canonical see [Tip 17](http://sitecore.stockpick.nl/english/sitecore-tips-and-tricks/) for search engines.

Or you can do a redirect if the url not match with the url you want.

Or block/redirect the url's in you netwerk/loadbalancer/webserver or redirect module or Sitecore `<httpRequestBegin>`pipeline. (just what you find convenient)

A simple solution is place a peace of code in your master page something like this:

```
string baseUrl = LinkManager.GetItemUrl(Sitecore.Context.Item);
if (baseUrl != Request.Path)
{
    Response.RedirectPermanent(baseUrl);
}
```

Also works for url aliases.

Comment: Canonical is not working as it is just effecting the database index but user can still hit/percept the two types of URL.

 i am trying 

string requestedUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower();


if (requestedUrl.Contains("/en/home"))
{
redirectUrl=requestedUrl.Replace("/en/home", "/en");
}


in redirect module but not working for me. Please provide some more input 

Above example is just for test, dont confuse with /en/home or / en

Comment: There are probably more urls try: /en/home.aspx and /en/home.ashx The item resolver can also handle it. The redirect code seems right for that particular URL. Where you put that code? Recommendation always use the Link Manager to generate a url.

Comment: Thanks alot, it did work. I used the same and everything is working perfectly fine now.

Really appreciate because i saw so many blogs contains same kind of problem, hope everyone will get help from this.

Comment: Hey, a new finding is that usually sitecore pages sets cookies so writing above piece of code was not working well with cookies.
so what i did is that added this chunk of codes inside where exception of root redirect was written.

string baseUrl = Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(Sitecore.Context.Item);
                        if (baseUrl != Request.Path)
                        {
                            Response.Redirect(baseUrl);
                        }
and now its working well with cookies like language code and country id.

Comment: Hi #jan bluemink, your tips worked perfectly for me, but here is a problem. We have nordic countries too in redirect, on applying these codes the nordic countries with querystring "?country=" is getting stucked in redirect loops. How I can customize your code using baseurl and request.path so that it works well with appended querystring. When I tried to do so than previous fix of my bug in which two url were working I.e one with /home and one without /home getting reproduce. Kindly help with ur suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you need to add the Querystring in the redirect baseUrl  + "?" + Request.Querystring; (if the link manager returns no query string, language location: file path) The compare is without querystring and to to use this on a multilingual site think about your LinkManager settings like languageLocation: filePath and languageEmbedding: always  if there is some complexity in the url you maby need to write some check before redirecting.

Comment: Thanks, what i did is : 
 string baseUrl=Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(Sitecore.Context.Item);
 baseUrl = Request.RawUrl.Substring(0, Request.RawUrl.IndexOf("?"));
 string ss = baseUrl;
 string Qurl = Request.RawUrl.Substring(0, Request.RawUrl.IndexOf("?"));
 string AppendedUrl = Request.RawUrl.Substring(Qurl.Length);
 string fullPath = Qurl + AppendedUrl;                       
 if (ss != fullPath)
 {
Response.RedirectPermanent(fullPath);
} but its still taking me into redirect loop in case querystring is request path.

Answer (score 0):

Use the IIS URL Rewrite module with the following rule:

```
<rule name="Redirect home" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^/en/home/?$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="/en/" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Hi, i tried it before and its do work after managing with section and other configuration but problem is that every one discourage to have change in config file in distributed environment. 
So, yes.. this is one of solution too so thanks, its just too much hard-coded.

Comment: I have a global platform running in 3 azure datacenters serving well over a million requests on a weekly basis using this. I'm interested to hear why config file changes are discouraged in a distributed environment. It depends on how you incorporate these changes in your project and automated build. Changing IIS configuration can be done in seconds/minutes. Changing code takes weeks.

Comment: Hey, maybe my explanation gone in bit wrong way. actually we have more than 25 locales and we wanted to implement this on every locale. you are absolutely correct. Config changes are so quick, was just bit complicated in my case.
so i have done a change in linkprovider.cs i.e
 if (item == null || item.Name.Equals("Home") || db == null)
                {  
                    url = string.Format("/{0}/", Sitecore.Context.Language.ToString()); 

and above piece of code by Jan Bluemink in main page and
its working fine for me, though thanks for best alternative solution too.

Comment: Doesn't matter how many locales you have if you can write regex. ea if you need to redirect any language url use this rule: <match url="^([^/]+)/home/?$"/><action type="Redirect" url="/{R:1}/" /> This basically catches the language part of your url to rewrite to, removing the home part. If you need to extend it to incorporate detecting extensions I can give you a rule for that too.

Comment: Yes please, do provide me so. That will be very helpful in different scenarios. I already noted down all the solutions i got from this page.

Thanks again Ivan. And, since i am newbies in development so can you please provide me suggestion to how to set up config section for this. I did it somehow but just wanted to get a confirmed solution from xperts.

Comment: Replace the /?$ with (/|\.[a-z]+)?$ to match the same URL with an extension as well. Setup your config `<rewrite><rules configSource="App_Config\RewriteRules.config" /></rewrite>` and preferably through a transform file.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of you guys all finally my bug is resolved and I came up with code which works in every situation like appended query string or without it.

```
string baseUrl = Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.GetItemUrl(Sitecore.Context.Item);
                if (baseUrl.ToLower().Contains("?"))
                {
                    baseUrl = Request.RawUrl.Substring(0, Request.RawUrl.IndexOf("?"));
                }
                string Qurl = Request.RawUrl;
                string AppendedUrl = string.Empty;

                if (Qurl.ToLower().Contains("?"))
                { 
                    Qurl = Request.RawUrl.Substring(0, Request.RawUrl.IndexOf("?")); 
                    AppendedUrl = Request.RawUrl.Substring(Qurl.Length);
                }
                string fullPath = baseUrl + AppendedUrl;
                if (baseUrl != Qurl)
                {
                    Response.RedirectPermanent(fullPath);
                }
            }
        }
```

Try this :)